# how to use same node_modules folder in another subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Suppose I have a File Structure like this

```
- Project_Folder
  | -node_modules
  | -project1
  | -project2
  | -project3
  | -package.json
```

Now I want to use same `node_modules` folder for all the `Project1` , `Project2` , `Project3` subfolders

Please Tell By how we use node_modules in subfolder

Comment: There is something called `pnpm`. It will use same node_modules files across all the projects in your system. Link: https://pnpm.io/

Comment: Do the subprojects have their own *package.json* files? If not, this should already work as-is.